# Why isn't the widget updating and how to set an imagebutton as selected

Tags: android, widget

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/activity_widget" >
</appwidget-provider>
```

Code:

```
...
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    Log.i("ExampleWidget",  "Updating widgets " + Arrays.asList(appWidgetIds));

    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this
    // provider
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        int k, p;
        k = 0;
        Log.d("Current SYSTEM", k+"");
    }
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views); //even though it is being called here, the function itself is greyed out, stating the method is never used.
}
...
//this function is greyed out stating, this method is never used... how come?
public static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
        RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_widget);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, updateViews);
        Log.d("UPDATED", "testing");
    }
```

When I add the widget to the homescreen, I see the `Log`, but even though I have the `updatePeriodMillis` set to 1, the `Log` isn't shown again (unless i remove the widget and readd it).

How do I display the `Log` based on the `updatePeriodMillis`

My second issue:

I have the following in Activity:

```
if (int u <= 0) {
    imageButton1.setSelected(true);
    ImageButton2.setSelected(false);
}
```

How can I imitate the same in a Widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is greyed out as unused because you are calling an overloaded version of that method, double check the parameters that you are passing

```
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

And

```
updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId)
```

More pinpointed hint

`appWidgetId, views` is different than `Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId`